# Compile FFMPEG in iOS with bitcode mode

Tags: ios, iphone, ffmpeg, ios9, bitcode

I compiled FFMPEG libs which supports for iOS 7 and 8 but since recent release with iOS 9  there is a new feature has issued which called bitcode mode , as a default setting , this setting  has set to NO .

But if i set this as yes  , following error will execute ,

libavdevice.a(avfoundation.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture arm64

Is there any way to  compile FFMPEG which supports FFMpeg in bitcode enabled mode

here is the build script i used

```
#!/bin/sh

# directories
SOURCE="ffmpeg-2.6.2"
FAT="FFmpeg-iOS"

SCRATCH="scratch"
# must be an absolute path
THIN=`pwd`/"thin"

# absolute path to x264 library
#X264=`pwd`/fat-x264

#FDK_AAC=`pwd`/fdk-aac/fdk-aac-ios

CONFIGURE_FLAGS="--enable-cross-compile --disable-debug --disable-programs \
                 --disable-doc --enable-pic"

if [ "$X264" ]
then
    CONFIGURE_FLAGS="$CONFIGURE_FLAGS --enable-gpl --enable-libx264"
fi

if [ "$FDK_AAC" ]
then
    CONFIGURE_FLAGS="$CONFIGURE_FLAGS --enable-libfdk-aac"
fi

# avresample
#CONFIGURE_FLAGS="$CONFIGURE_FLAGS --enable-avresample"

ARCHS="arm64 armv7 x86_64 i386"

COMPILE="y"
LIPO="y"

DEPLOYMENT_TARGET="6.0"

if [ "$*" ]
then
    if [ "$*" = "lipo" ]
    then
        # skip compile
        COMPILE=
    else
        ARCHS="$*"
        if [ $# -eq 1 ]
        then
            # skip lipo
            LIPO=
        fi
    fi
fi

if [ "$COMPILE" ]
then
    if [ ! `which yasm` ]
    then
        echo 'Yasm not found'
        if [ ! `which brew` ]
        then
            echo 'Homebrew not found. Trying to install...'
            ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)" \
                || exit 1
        fi
        echo 'Trying to install Yasm...'
        brew install yasm || exit 1
    fi
    if [ ! `which gas-preprocessor.pl` ]
    then
        echo 'gas-preprocessor.pl not found. Trying to install...'
        (curl -L https://github.com/libav/gas-preprocessor/raw/master/gas-preprocessor.pl \
            -o /usr/local/bin/gas-preprocessor.pl \
            && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/gas-preprocessor.pl) \
            || exit 1
    fi

    if [ ! -r $SOURCE ]
    then
        echo 'FFmpeg source not found. Trying to download...'
        curl http://www.ffmpeg.org/releases/$SOURCE.tar.bz2 | tar xj \
            || exit 1
    fi

    CWD=`pwd`
    for ARCH in $ARCHS
    do
        echo "building $ARCH..."
        mkdir -p "$SCRATCH/$ARCH"
        cd "$SCRATCH/$ARCH"

        CFLAGS="-arch $ARCH"
        if [ "$ARCH" = "i386" -o "$ARCH" = "x86_64" ]
        then
            PLATFORM="iPhoneSimulator"
            CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -mios-simulator-version-min=$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET"
        else
            PLATFORM="iPhoneOS"
            CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -mios-version-min=$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET"
            if [ "$ARCH" = "arm64" ]
            then
                EXPORT="GASPP_FIX_XCODE5=1"
            fi
        fi

        XCRUN_SDK=`echo $PLATFORM | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`
        CC="xcrun -sdk $XCRUN_SDK clang"
        CXXFLAGS="$CFLAGS"
        LDFLAGS="$CFLAGS"
        if [ "$X264" ]
        then
            CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -I$X264/include"
            LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -L$X264/lib"
        fi
        if [ "$FDK_AAC" ]
        then
            CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -I$FDK_AAC/include"
            LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -L$FDK_AAC/lib"
        fi

        TMPDIR=${TMPDIR/%\/} $CWD/$SOURCE/configure \
            --target-os=darwin \
            --arch=$ARCH \
            --cc="$CC" \
            $CONFIGURE_FLAGS \
            --extra-cflags="$CFLAGS" \
            --extra-cxxflags="$CXXFLAGS" \
            --extra-ldflags="$LDFLAGS" \
            --prefix="$THIN/$ARCH" \
        || exit 1

        make -j3 install $EXPORT || exit 1
        cd $CWD
    done
fi

if [ "$LIPO" ]
then
    echo "building fat binaries..."
    mkdir -p $FAT/lib
    set - $ARCHS
    CWD=`pwd`
    cd $THIN/$1/lib
    for LIB in *.a
    do
        cd $CWD
        echo lipo -create `find $THIN -name $LIB` -output $FAT/lib/$LIB 1>&2
        lipo -create `find $THIN -name $LIB` -output $FAT/lib/$LIB || exit 1
    done

    cd $CWD
    cp -rf $THIN/$1/include $FAT
fi

echo Done
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got it working using the following CONFIGURE_FLAGS:

```
CONFIGURE_FLAGS="--enable-cross-compile --disable-debug --disable-programs \
                 --disable-doc --enable-pic \
                 --extra-cflags=-fembed-bitcode --extra-cxxflags=-fembed-bitcode"
```

If you only need to decode videos, you should add more flags to disable all muxers,encoders. You'll also probably don't need filters. This will save some space. I also disabled the ARCH i386, which is not needed for the iOS simulator.

I use these flags for my project:

```
CONFIGURE_FLAGS="--enable-cross-compile --disable-debug --disable-programs \
                 --disable-doc --enable-pic \
                 --extra-cflags=-fembed-bitcode --extra-cxxflags=-fembed-bitcode \
                 --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl \
                 --disable-ffserver --disable-ffmpeg   --disable-ffprobe \
                 --disable-avdevice --disable-avfilter --disable-encoders \
                 --disable-parsers  --disable-decoders --disable-protocols \
                 --disable-filters  --disable-muxers   --disable-bsfs \
                 --disable-indevs   --disable-outdevs  --disable-demuxers \
                 --enable-protocol=file \
                 --enable-protocol=tcp \
                 --enable-protocol=udp \
                 --enable-decoder=msmpeg4v3 \
                 --enable-decoder=mpeg4 \
                 --enable-decoder=mjpeg \
                 --enable-decoder=h264 \
                 --enable-parser=mpeg4video \
                 --enable-parser=mjpeg \
                 --enable-parser=h263 \
                 --enable-parser=h264 \
                 --enable-parser=aac \
                 --enable-demuxer=avi \
                 --enable-demuxer=mov \
                 --enable-demuxer=rtsp \
                 "
```

Comment: If you - like me - only want to support RTSP streams, you can also disable the avi and mov demuxers and the h263 and mpeg4video parsers as well as the msmpeg4v4 and mpeg4 decoders. I also disabled the file protocol. Works great!

Comment: can yo please tell me how set this flags for pods. I have installed library using pod but due to  min gpl issue can't compress using x265 ! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add -fembed-bitcode-marker to CONFIGURE_FLAGS

like this:

```
CONFIGURE_FLAGS="--enable-cross-compile --disable-debug --disable-programs \
             --disable-doc --enable-pic -fembed-bitcode-marker"
```